# For IOS, how to change the section title after init?

Tags: ios

Firstly, I return hello as the section title.And I want to change the section title to "hi" after I click a custom button? How to toggle the titleForHeadInsection method?

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"hello";
}
```

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350124/uitableview-section-header-how-to-change-text

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is to reload whole table:

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

More optimize version will reload a given section only, but you probably not at the stage of optimizing yet.

Comment: hhhhhh….   I really want to take the optimizing method….Because my project have many insert rows, and delete rows options… I just ask the question by a simple example

Answer (score 0):

Store the section title in a property in your `UIViewController`, or whatever class is acting as your `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *sectionTitle;
```

And set its value to `@"hello"` somewhere.
Then when in your button press method, update self.sectionTitle with the new title.

```
self.sectionTitle = @"hi";
```

Then reload your entire UITableView or reload the appropriate section.

```
[tableView reloadData]; // Entire
```

Or

```
NSIndexSet *sectionIndex = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];                                     
[self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; 
// Specific section
```